# SQLite - What setup do I use to associate entries on one table using a separate links

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am very new to SQL, and while somewhat familiar with the basic concepts of many to many and one to many, and such, I can't quite figure out what configuration would be best to use with this setup: Basically I have a table of people, and a separate table that links each person to several other people. I want to be able to select a person/entry on the main table, and automatically display all the people they are linked to. The two tables look like this:

```
Person Table

1-John
2-Tom
3-Mary
4-Bob
5-Susy

Links Table
PersonA-PersonB
1-2
1-3
1-4
3-2
3-4


Display John and all links...

John
Tom
Mary
Bob
```

I'm not looking for a spelled out query or anything like that. Just some advice on what kind of setup I should be learning about in order to set this up. I know this is a very basic concept, but in spite of the research I've done, I'm still finding this[sql] very confusing, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'John'

union all

select  p2.person_name

from            Person as p1

        join    (      select PersonA,PersonB from Links
                 union select PersonB,PersonA from Links
                ) as l
        on      p1.person_id = l.PersonA

        join    Person as p2
        on      p2.person_id = l.PersonB 

where   p.person_name = 'John'
```

---

```
(      select PersonA,PersonB from Links
 union select PersonB,PersonA from Links
) as l
```

might be changed to

```
(          select PersonA,PersonB from Links
 union all select PersonB,PersonA from Links
) as l
```

or

```
Links as l
```

depending on your data